# Restrict Write Operation(PUT) on ElastiCache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We've an usecase where we need to use ElastiCache securely(We've few set of users where who can WRITE and others can READ only to avoid accidentally changing data in the cache).

Have went through AWS ElastiCache documentation and found that We can restrict the permissions of some of the Actions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/IAM.APIReference.html).

But don't see an option to restrict PUT option on the Cache Node. Can someone please let me know the pointers to achieve make Cache ReadOnly for few users?